# Second cin is either skipped or does not work properly

Tags: c++, linux, macos, cin

I have a couple of problems, that I think are closely connected, but I couldn't get them fixed following what I previously found on the website.

My problems are related to the double use of `cin` in my main function. I need to read numbers from keyboard in order to either build small vectors or store single coefficients. I cannot know in advance the length of the vectors that I am going to build.

Here are the lines involved:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    ...
    double a=0;
    std::vector<double> coefficients;
    while (std::cin>>a) {
       coefficients.push_back(a);
    }
    ...
    std::vector<double> interval;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    while(std::cin>>a) {
       interval.push_back(a);
    }
    std::cout<<interval.size()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<*interval.cbegin()<<" "<<*(interval.cend()-1)<<std::endl;
    ...
}
```

I am using both macOS with g++ 6.3.0 and Linux with g++ 5.3.0. The flags I send to the compiler are `-Wall -std=c++14 -o`.
On the macOS machine the second cin is completely skipped, while on the Linux one the second reading process does not behave like it is expected to. I mean that if i give `-1 1` at the second `cin`, the printed vector size is 0 and, obviously, the program stops because of a segmentation fault.

At each `cin` I enter the requested numbers in a single line, like `1 0 0 1`, then press enter and then ctrl+D.

Thanks in advance to all! :)

Comment: Have you considered using `getline` instead?

Comment: Yeah I did and that, alongside with getting rid of the `cin.ignore` line, lets my code run as expected on the Linux machine. However, this is not the case for the macOS one.
So, I should give up `cin` once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call of `std::cin.ignore(...)` set the fail bit of the stream. This makes it impossible to enter the loop. You need to move the `std::cin.clear()` call right before the loop, in order to make it run. Also you have an out-of-bound read when there are no data in the second container.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main() {
    double a=0;
    std::vector<double> coefficients;
    while (std::cin>>a) {
       coefficients.push_back(a);
    }
    std::cout << coefficients.size() << '\n';

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), 'X');
    std::cin.clear();
    char c;
    std::cin>>c;
    if(c != 'X')
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid separator\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<double> interval;
    while(std::cin >> a) {
       interval.push_back(a);
    }
    std::cout<< interval.size()<<std::endl;
    if(interval.size())
        std::cout<<*interval.cbegin()<<" "<<*(interval.cend()-1)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With the following data file,

```
$ cat data.txt
12 23
42
X
1 2
3 4 5
```

this output is generated:

```
$ ./a.out < data                  
3
5
1 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that `std::cin.ignore()` sets the fail bit of the stream. Now the program runs well on Linux. Still unchanged on macOS, but that is secondary now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a linefeed `'\n'` as a second parameter to `cin.ignore()` so it kills the ignore on an enter press

Comment: Yeah I have tried that as well, but nothing changes. On macOS the second cin is just skipped and on Linux it still does not work as I explained above.