# Could I use `std::cin` for another input if I've exited it using `Ctrl+D`(EOF)?

Tags: c++, inputstream

I have this exercise from Programming principles and practice using C++ by B. Stroustrup:

> 2. Design and implement a `Name_pairs` class holding (name,age) pairs where
>    name is a `string` and age is a `double` . Represent that as a `vector<string>`
>    (called `name` ) and a `vector<double>` (called `age` ) member. Provide an input operation `read_names()` that reads a series of names. Provide a `read_ ages()` operation that prompts the user for an age for each name. Provide
>    a `print()` operation that prints out the ( `name[i]` , `age[i]` ) pairs (one per line)
>    in the order determined by the `name` vector. Provide a `sort()` operation
>    that sorts the `name` vector in alphabetical order and reorganizes the `age` vector to match. Implement all "operations" as member functions. Test
>    the class (of course: test early and often).

Here I show the part that causes the problem only for the brevity sake:

```
std::istream& Name_pairs::read_names(std::istream& in){
    for(std::string str; in >> str; )
        name.push_back(str);
    in.clear();
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');


 // the following lines are added just for testing the stream state
    int x;
    std::cout << "x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    return in;
}
```

Now if I call the member function:

```
 Name_pairs{}.read_names(std::cin);
```

I get prompted to enter names until I hit `EOF` (`Ctrl+D`). At that moment I follow it by `clear` and `ignore` to reset the input buffer. But I am not prompted to input `x`!!?

- I've seen some suggestions that I should trigger a constant string as an exit mark like `std::string quit = "quit; if(str == quit) break;` but I don't want this; I want to use `Ctrl+d` then get input again. In other words can I use the input stream after pressing `Ctrl+D`?
- I've tried the very program on windows 10 and Code::blocks for windows and it worked fine! I press `Ctrl+D`; the loop breaks then I am prompted to input `x`.
- So how could I fix the problem? thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you so much! would you suggest the best way for my case please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Second cin is either skipped or does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936723/second-cin-is-either-skipped-or-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 3):

There is no *standard* way to reuse a closed/terminated stream, including `cin`.

Once `cin` is closed/terminated, it can't be reused by *standard* means. However, there *may* be non-standard, platform-specific ways to reopen it.  Check your compiler/platform documentation.

That being said, nothing in the requirements you have shown will prevent you from prompting the user for the number of names to enter and then using an ordinary `for` loop, or simply asking the user to enter a termination string to stop reading.  Rather than relying on <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> to stop the reading, which is very platform-specific behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It works on Windows because `Ctrl+D` isn't the EOF key combo on Windows, it's the [end-of-text character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character). `Ctrl+Z` (plus `Enter`) is the EOF marker on Windows.

If `cin` actually hits EOF, it's done. Your code only works on Windows because you didn't actually hit EOF on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The most common (and obnoxious, IMHO) way is to first ask *how many*.

```
std::vector <std::string> names;
int n;
std::cout << "How many names? ";
std::cin >> n;
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

while (n--)
{
  std::string name;
  getline( std::cin, name );
  names.push_back( name );
}
```

The way *I* prefer is to simply terminate on the first empty line:

```
std::vector <std::string> names;
std::cout << "Enter names, one per line. Press ENTER twice to finish.\n";
while (true)
{
  std::cout << "name? ";
  std::string name;
  getline( std::cin, name );
  if (name.empty()) break;
  names.push_back( name );
}
```

Now that you have a vector of names, you can ask for an age to go with each one:

```
std::vector <int> ages;
for (auto name : names)
{
  std::cout << name << "’s age? ";
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  ages.push_back( n );
}
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Another common way, which is a variation of the “*empty line*” method I just showed you, is to use a **sentinel** value to terminate the input. It can be anything, like having the user enter “done” as the final name, or “-1” or something. You can guess my opinion on that nonsense.

As always, make sure you are reading your assignment correctly. If unsure, email your professor and ask clarification. Remember to ask an *intelligent* question, which shows your professor you aren’t just begging for an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! The suggestion of hitting enter twice looks great in this scenario for the fact that no name can be empty or all white-space.